# Background Image when RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

Do you know how to set a background image when the recycler view is empty? Like  Gmail app... 
Question 2: is there a repository where I can find official images by Google for this purpose?
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeNWW.png)

Comment: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons .. for images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an official, Google maintained Github repository. Contains the latest version of their material icons, which are used on all Google apps.

[Google's Material Design Icons Repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)

And, regarding your first question: yes.

You can check if the adapter you are using to populate your RecyclerView is empty (or/and if the adapter has no items). If true, show the image, else, deal with the RecyclerView. Like this:

```
if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
    // show my background image
    // do stuff
} else {
    // RecyclerView stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on @herrmartell answer and to manage streched drawables as background: This solution switches the howl recView for another linearlayout having the same effect as you request but looks in my case prettier after trying lots of different possibilities. If you change your list you have to call the handler function abviously again.

Your Fragment that handles the RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        //setup recView like -> recView = view.findViewById(R.id.yourListRecyclerView);
        //adapter setup
        //set to recView
        handleRecyclerViewState(view);
}
private void handleRecyclerViewState(View view) {
    View emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        recView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        recView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Inside your RecView layout xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/yourListRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    layout="@layout/empty_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

</include>
```

Exact layouting and design might differ for sure.

Here the Layout of the empty_view.xml that shows a drawable svg image and a message underneath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/empty_image"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_no_files" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Nothing here!"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColor" />
```